# Given person to person relationships, find family groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, grouping

I need to return **family groups** from normalised person-to-person relationship data.

The data that stores person-to-person relationships is in the following structure (which I can't change), in which each relationship between people is expressed in a pair of rows, identifying each of the parties and with a FK to the related row in the table.

```
create table myRelationships (
    id int
   ,PersonID int
   ,RelatedRowID int -- this is a FK to id for the related pair row
   ,RelationshipTypeID int -- not important for the purposes of this question
)
```

I can get as far as sensibly returning each relationship in a single row:

```
select
    r1.PersonID as Person1ID
   ,r2.PersonID as Person2ID
   ,r1.RelationshipTypeID as P1toP2RelationshipType
from
    myRelationships as r1
    left join myRelationships as r2 on r1.RelatedRowID=r2.id
where
    r1.PersonID<r2.PersonID -- so we don't get the same relationship in mirror-image as a 'duplicate'
```

I now need to **group this data by 'families'**, where all people related to each other either directly or n-degrees-removed (e.g. related to someone who is related to someone...) are grouped into the same bucket. Following is some sample data, and the expected results. Note that the relationship type in this case doesn't matter - assume all relationship types express familial relationships that meet my criteria for family grouping.

```
insert into myRelationships
    values (1,1,2,1)
          ,(2,2,1,1)
          ,(3,1,4,1)
          ,(4,3,3,1)
          ,(5,4,6,1)
          ,(6,5,5,1)
          ,(7,1,8,1)
          ,(8,6,7,1)
          ,(9,7,10,1)
          ,(10,15,9,1)
          ,(11,8,12,1)
          ,(12,15,11,1)
```

Desired output

```
FamilyGroup PersonID
1           1
1           2
1           3
1           6
2           4
2           5
3           7
3           8
3           15
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of how to do it with CTE:s. For performance reasons you might want to break out some of the CTE:s into temp tables with indexes instead.

Edit, the first solution did not work. This is a new try with recursions both up and down the tree. Therefore I need to keep track what I have recursed on in a 'list' (column just called x in this code). This way you find the minimum related id from each person and then you can group on that minimum id. Not sure if this will be performant enough on large data sets though.

```
with ordered_relations as (
    select r1.PersonID as id1, r2.PersonID as id2
    from myRelationships r1
        inner join myRelationships r2 on r2.id = r1.RelatedRowID
    where r1.PersonID < r2.PersonID
)
, rec as (
  select ',' + cast(r.id1 as varchar(max)) + ',' x, r.id1 as id, r.id1 as minid
  from ordered_relations r
  union all
  select x + cast(r.id2 as varchar) + ',', r.id2, t.minid
  from rec t
    inner join ordered_relations r on r.id1 = t.id
    and not t.x like '%,' + cast(r.id2 as varchar) + ',%'
  union all
  select x + cast(r.id1 as varchar) + ',', r.id1, case when r.id1 < t.minid then r.id1 else t.minid end
  from rec t
    inner join ordered_relations r on r.id2 = t.id
    and not t.x like '%,' + cast(r.id1 as varchar) + ',%'
)
select dense_rank() over (order by min(minid)) groupid, id
from rec
group by id;
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks a million! Out of interest, do you have some references for this or is it just something you've done a lot of times?

Comment: Glad I could help :) Recursive sql isn't that common for me but I remembered how to do it this time so I have no reference for this particular problem. In general though, if you want to learn how to master t-sql, I can say that the "Inside Microsoft SQL Server" book series by Itzik Ben-Gan is fantastic.

Comment: Bummer, unfortunately this solution doesn't properly resolve relationships between 2 people on the "left side" if a mediating person exists only on the right hand side... If we add row pairs for relationship between people {7,15} and {8,15}, we should see persons 7, 8 and 15 in a single group.

Comment: I'm un-accepting this answer in hopes a small tweak can restore it as the accepted answer - feels very close

Comment: Sorry about that, I obviously made a big logical mistake in thinking you could find the "roots" that easily. Also noticed a mistake in the recursive part (it's actually not recursive right now). Will see if I can find a solution.

Comment: Edited my answer above with a new attempt at a solution. Hope this works better.

Comment: Thinking a bit more, using the hierarchyid data type could help in detecting recursion loop instead of the varchar hack. Was a while since I used it though.

Comment: Great, this seems to work, I've mucked around with different combinations of relationships and it correctly groups people even if they are related by a RHS-only person. Nice. Not sure how soon I'll have an opportunity to test this on a large dataset, but I'm happy with this as it answers the question and behaves as required.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with hierarchical structure such as this for many years, and I do not know of a way to construct a single SQL statement that will get you the desired output.  Tree structures, as they are also called, make perfect sense to computers, but are a pain to work with in real life.  This is why Microsoft created the hierarchyid datatype.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677213(v=sql.110).aspx

Since you already said you can't change the existing data table, if you want to return the data formatted from SQL, you will need to either create a stored procedure that can process the recursive logic and return a data table structure, or create a Common Table Expression (CTE).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

What you refer to as a 'FamilyGroup', the example at the MSFT link about calls levels.